# No Login Page shown with Keycloak and Quarkus

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

I have a keycloak Server running on my localhost with port 8081.
I'm trying to connect my Quarkus application with it to secure REST-Endpoints.
However I'm not able to Login to my Keycloak server.
I annotated an /test endpoint with @RolesAllowed("user"). Since then I can't access the endpoint but I get an Empty page with a 401 Unauthorized error in the Web console.
What I want is that I get redirected to the Keycloak default page so I can authorize myself. Any ideas why that is not happening?

Here is my application.properties Keycloak configuration:

```
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8081/realms/TestRealm
quarkus.oidc.client-id=testclient
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=MYSECRET
quarkus.oidc.tls.verification=none
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=false
logging.level.org.keycloak=DEBUG
resteasy.role.based.security=true
quarkus.http.cors=true
quarkus.http.port=8080
```

when I set policy enforcer to true I can't access any endpoint.
TestRealm has a Resource configured with a /test endpoint.

In the Quarkus documentation for keycloak they said that you don't need to setup your own Keycloak Server in Dev mode since Quarkus comes with one. Might that be the Problem? is my Quarkus Application not connecting to my Keycloak server? And if so, how can I force quarkus in dev mode to use my Keycloak server?

EDIT: I figured out that I have access to my endpoint if I send the request with the Bearer token, so I guess Quarkus is accessing my Keycloak instance.
Still, why don't I get forwarded to the default Keycloak login page when trying to access my Rest endpoint via my browser? Am I missing any configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with the same issue I fixed it by adding:

```
quarkus.oidc.auth-mechanism=keycloak
quarkus.oidc.application-type=web-app
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.paths=/*
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.policy=authenticated
```

To the config

Comment: Thanks Matteo, right, `quarkus.oidc.application-type=web-app` enables an authorization code flow support, I'm assuming though that with `quarkus.oidc.auth-mechanism=keycloak` you meant `quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8081/realms/TestRealm` as `quarkus.oidc.auth-mechanism` property is not available in the `quarkus.oidc` namespace

Comment: Yeah your correct @SergeyBeryozkin, quarkus.oidc.auth-mechanism doesn't exist, I got it from somewhere in the internet but your right.
I also changed web-app to hyprid since I wanted to use http bearer tokens authorization as well.
I also had the issue, that quarkus couldn't find the roles from the jwt token so I had to add an extra role claim and told quarkus to use it: quarkus.oidc.roles.role-claim-path=roles